# Getting Extra argument 'animated' in call

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I try to go to another storyboard programmatically I use

```
//Pop user to next screen
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil);
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("home") as UIViewController;
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

But that doesn't show the navigation controller on the next story board. So I did

```
HomeViewController.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

And all that throws is

> Extra argument 'animated' in call

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of observations regarding your first question:

- For the first issue, you might want to make sure that `vc` was not `nil` (e.g. that a scene with the storyboard id of `home` was found):

  ```
  if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("home") as? UIViewController {
      presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  } else {
      println("home not found")
  }
  ```
- I'd suggest you double check the spelling and capitalization for that "Storyboard id" for the "home" scene.
- BTW, if you've checked the "Is Initial View Controller" checkbox in IB for the first scene in your second storyboard, then you can alternatively do:

  ```
  let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
  ```

  You can visually confirm this setting because the scene will have a little "initial segue" arrow pointing into it from the left:

  [image: initial view controller]
- If you are doing a `presentViewController` to a destination scene that is, itself, itself, embedded in navigation controller, then you should present that navigation controller (i.e. give the navigation controller's scene the "storyboard id" or specify it as "Is Initial View Controller"), rather than to the scene that is embedded within that navigation controller.

Regarding your second error, that's because you're calling an instance method `presentViewController`, but are referencing what is presumably a class name, `HomeViewController`, rather than an instance. This syntax simply doesn't make any sense at all.

The former syntax with `self.presentViewController(...)` is probably right, but more than likely the storyboard or scene were not found, either because the name of one or the other (most likely the scene's "storyboard id") or because the scoreboard was not included in the bundle (though I think that would have generated a different error).

Comment: Well if I drag a label into the next view controller I can see it. It's just the navigation controller that's not showing.

Comment: You have to give that navigation controller a unique storyboard id of its own and reference _that_ in your code, (or, for the navigation controller's scene check the "is initial view controller" checkbox and then use the `instantiateInitialViewController` syntax).

Comment: That's what I'm using the second line for. I already set the storyboard ID in interface builder to `home`

Comment: And you specified this storyboard id not on your scene to which you just added the label, but rather the navigation controller scene before that scene, right?

Comment: There we go! I was adding it to the view not the view controller. Thanks tons, I spent hours on this.